# Force to run delayed task Celery

Tags: django, task, celery

I have a celery task with countdown, and I want to force this task to run.

```py
task_id = uuid()
timer.apply_async(
    args=(self.room_group_name,
          cache.get(f'{self.room_name}_round'),
          cache.get(f'{self.room_name}_round') > self.total_rounds
          ),
          countdown=self.timer'
          task_id=task_id
)
```

now I revoke this task and create another task.
Is there any possibility to force run celery task with countdown?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown